# C# Get classes that has a reference to a specific type

Tags: c#, types, reference, using-statement

In my project I would like to know the references of a specific type within my C# project. For example I have the class `EntityA`.

I have two other classes `ProcessA` and `ProcessB`. `ProcessA` and `ProcessB` used a reference to `EntityA`. Is there a solution to get all references via the type of `EntityA`? In my case `ProcessA` and `ProcessB`?

I have been searching on the internet, but cannot find a possible solution for this.

Thank you in advance!

Jelle

Edit:

EntityA:

```
public class EntityA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

ProcessA:

```
public class ProcessA
{
    public void Init()
    {
        var entity = new EntityA();
        entity.Name = "John Doe";
        entity.Age = 45;
    }
}
```

ProcessB:

```
public class ProcessB
{
    public void Init()
    {
        var entity = new EntityA();
        entity.Name = "Peter Doe";
        entity.Age = 32;
    }
}
```

I would like to know programmatically in which other classes EntityA is used. In my Example is ProcessA and ProcessB.

Comment: Please, share your code

Comment: Yes, especially share the code for "ProcessA and ProcessB used a reference to EntityA".

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by `ProcessA and ProcessB used a reference to EntityA`. Is that a `using` statement? is that a method call? is that inheritance?

Comment: Do you want to do this by code or just in VS interactivly? For the latter it´s just "find all references" within the context-menu on your class, for the former this question is way to broad.

Comment: I have editted my question. I would like to achieve this via code, not via VS.

Comment: This is a huge project an relative long running code, you have to access all the referenced libaries, load all the types in it, check all the Methods, All Delegates, All Fields and Properties, for a specific type, worst thing is you have to scan all the IL-Instructions if there is anywhere a generic type created like new List<T>.
What about interfaces, you want to scan for any implementation on each single method ? Maybe there is an existing library for this, but this is just to huge to put this here in code sample windows.